# apache rewrite all my php pages to htm and fobidden all .php request

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

as the title,I want to rewrite all my php pages to 'htm',and fobidden all .php request , people can visit pages only by url like '***.htm?querystring' but cannot get result by '***.php' ,what should i do?I write the rules below but it dosent work(all page is 404)

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.htm$ $1\.php [QSA,PT,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ 404 [QSA,PT,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

# block .php extension
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php[\?\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]

# convert .htm/.html to .php
RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.html?$ $1.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: doen't work,the's a error in apache log,"request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary",seems like a endless loop